# What is the correct way to set the maximum number of vehicles in SUMO?

Tags: python-3.x, numbers, sumo, vehicle-routing

I am new to [`SUMO` (Simulation of Urban MObility)](https://www.eclipse.org/sumo/). I tried to create a simulation with 30 vehicles with the following code:

`sumo -n map.net.xml -r map.rou.xml --step-length 0.1 --fcd-output Parsed.txt --device.fcd.period 0.01 --max-num-vehicles 30`

When it was running, I noticed the warning that appeared in the command line said: `Warning: Vehicle '75' performs emergency ...` and after it finished I got a mobility history of more than 30 vehicles (specifically 279 vehicles), which was not what I expected.

How can I force the simulation to use only 30 vehicles?

Comment: What is included in your route file (.rou.xml)? Are you using flows? Keep in mind that the `--max-num-vehicles` delays the insertion of vehicles to keep them in limit, in your case 30.

Answer (score 1):

`--max-num-vehicles` refers to the number of vehicles which are *simultaneously* in the net. If you want to limit the total number for the whole simulation, you can just add up all the flows or count the vehicles in your route file.

Comment: Thank you. Could you show me how to add the flows or count the vehicles, please? I read the instruction on SUMO's page but it was too vague for me to follow.

Comment: Just take your route file and count every occurence of "<vehicle ...>". If you have flows add up the "number" attributes of them too.